# Cakephp multiple user types login

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I am very new to cakephp so kindly bear with me. I am working on a small assignment and I have completed many things in it but I am struck on a problem. My assignment has two different user types for which I need two different logins or may be one login which will redirect them. I read the official tutorial about using User model, controller and table but problem with that is it is for one user type only. What I want is as soon as my application is opened a login page is displayed and depending upon user type (admin or employee) they will be redirected towards their respective index pages.
I have created employee table and admin table and both contain username and password fields. Tutorial says that user table should have username and password field but I don't want to use user table because I already have these fields in both the tables. So is it possible to not use user table at all and use my current tables for user login and authentication. Kindly guide me because I am on this problem from last several hours. Will be very thankful for help or guidance provided.

Answer (score 1):

You could use only one model (`User`) and have a field called `type` whose values can be `admin` and `employe`.

This way you will not have the same fields in more tables, you will be able to have only one login form, and after the user has logged in, you can redirect the user to the right page.

In the `Auth` component, you will always know what type of user the current logged person is, so you can use this in other controllers.

In `AppController`, you can have

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login'
         ),
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'dashboard'
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ),
        'authorize' => array('Controller')
    )
);
```

The `UsersController` - `dashboard` method, will be called after the user has just logged in, so here you can get the user type and redirect to the correct page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I get it what you are saying but loginRedirect and logutRedirect can be defined for either user not both and I have defined it for employee. But what if the user role is admin? Where to define that condition? Can I use two $components or I need to define it on UsersController page? Can you tell me that? IT'll be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is not very sound. What if an admin and a user have the same username? All users should be on the same table with a differentiating `user_type_id` or equivalent.

But if you want to stick on your current scheme **and** have them login in the same page then you are left with only attempting to login a person as a user, if it succeeds redirect to users page and if it fails try again as admin which if it succeeds redirect to the admin page if it fails means the username/password is invalid for both cases. This way at least you get *some* kind of basic security.

Comment: Or just a simple role/role_id field. Tip: [tiny](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/18/tinyauth-the-fastest-and-easiest-authorization-for-cake2/)